# Hide sections of specific chapter from table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

How do I hide all the sections and subsections of one chapter from the contents page?

What I want is if I have this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, draft, titlepage]{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{This chapter is listed in the contents page}
\section{So are all its sections}
\subsection{--- and subsections!}

\chapter{This chapter name is listed in the contents page}
\section{But this section doesn't appear on the contents page.}
\subsection{This section doesn't appear on the contents page either.}
\end{document}
```

I want it to appear like this:
[image: How I want the image to appear]

But of course, it appears like this:
[image]

Is there any way I can hide all the sections and subsections of that specific chapter?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can change the value of the counter `tocdepth` mid-document, writing it to the ToC at the appropriate spot. This allows you to vary what shows and what doesn't show.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This chapter is listed in the contents page}
\section{So are all its sections}
\subsection{--- and subsections!}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
% From this point on, only show up to \chapters in the ToC

\chapter{This chapter name is listed in the contents page}
\section{But this section doesn't appear on the contents page.}
\subsection{This section doesn't appear on the contents page either.}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
% From this point on, only show up to \subsection in the ToC
\chapter{This chapter is listed in the contents page}
\section{So are all its sections}
\subsection{--- and subsections!}

\end{document}
```

Sectional units have the following "level":

- `-1` = `\part`
- `0` = `\chapter`
- `1` = `\section`
- `2` = `\subsection`
- `3` = `\subsubsection`
- `4` = `\paragraph`
- `5` = `\subparagraph`

Other document classes may offer different levels.